# add ssl certificate in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ssl-certificate

Please tell me how to validate or add ssl certificate in ios swift 4.how to validate a certificate from server is trusted or not.  please tell me how to do that complete process step by step

here is my code to make a request of server:

```
let soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetLeaveApprove xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><Token>\(token)</Token><ReferenceNo>\(ReferenceNo)</ReferenceNo><Stage>\(Stage)</Stage><Action>\(Action)</Action><Remarks>\(remarks)</Remarks></GetLeaveApprove></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    let urlString = URL(string:"https://in.megasoftsol.com/ehrms.test/HRMSServices.asmx")

    let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlString!)
    let msgLength: String = "\(soapMessage.count)"
    theRequest.addValue("in.megasoftsol.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    theRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.httpBody = soapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest as URLRequest, delegate: self)

    if (connection != nil)
    {
        webResponseData = self.webResponseData as Data
        print("\(webResponseData)")
        connection?.start()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Certificates if you dont get through server**

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.infinum.co:443 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > infinumco.cer

**PINNING WITH SWIFT AND ALAMOFIRE Make sure you use session manager reference and use that for your request.**

```
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "infinum.co": .pinPublicKeys(
        publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(),
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
    )
]

let sessionManager = SessionManager( // Make sure you keep a reference of this guy somewhere
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(
        policies: serverTrustPolicies
    )
)
```

**Everything is exactly the same as the default pinning implementation, except now this class needs to be used instead.**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class CustomServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {

    override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
        // Check if we have a policy already defined, otherwise just kill the connection
        if let policy = super.serverTrustPolicy(forHost: host) {
            print(policy)
            return policy
        } else {
            return .customEvaluation({ (_, _) -> Bool in
                return false
            })
        }
    }

}
```

**You can either pin a certificate:**

```
if let serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0) {
    let serverCertificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(serverCertificate) as Data

    if pinnedCertificates().contains(serverCertificateData) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
        return
    }
}
```

**Or a public key:**

```
// Or, compare the public keys
if let serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0), let serverCertificateKey = publicKey(for: serverCertificate) {
    if pinnedKeys().contains(serverCertificateKey) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me complete process where we have to mention our certificate name and which extension of will use of certificate and where we have to validate cetificate when we are making a request of server in sop xml

Comment: if you need a tutorial
https://dzone.com/articles/ssl-certificate-pinning-in-ios-applications

https://www.bugsee.com/blog/ssl-certificate-pinning-in-mobile-applications/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/641-charles-proxy-tutorial-for-ios

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/securing-communications-on-ios--cms-28529

https://medium.com/@Dranko/certificate-pinning-your-android-and-ios-apps-6506972ecb37

Comment: follow any one which you think is good enough for your understanding